# Inconsistent execution order of link functions for two nested directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

We are facing some weird behaviour in the execution of link functions of 2 nested custom AngularJS directives:

1/ The first time (or each time after a hard page refresh) the linking function of the outer directive is executed before the linking function of the inner directive --> this is how we expect/want it, since parameters are passed from the outer to the inner directive.

2/ But then, each time the directive is used again, eg. after navigating away from the view and returning to it (without ever refreshing the page), the execution of the linking functions gets reversed: i.e. the linking function of the inner directive is executed before the linking function of the outer directive.

This, obviously, results in errors, since params passed from the outer directive to the inner directive (which are used in the link function) are not yet existing.

We are puzzled by this problem for quite some time now, so we hope there are some bright minds out there that may be able to help us out here :-) Tx in advance!

Comment: All browsers? Can you reproduce the error with a small example?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the priority value of the directives?

It is easily described in the priority chapter of this [Article](http://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-directive/#highlighter_97806)